# Creating new folders and files with Lua

Tags: file, file-io, lua, directory, execute

I'm writing a Lua 5.1 script for personal use, designed to be run as a stand-alone program through the Lua interpreter. I need to include a function that will create a new subfolder (where "mainfolder" contains the script and a folder titled "season", and the new folder is created as a subfolder of "season"), then write the text string returned by another function to a new text file within the new folder. This is on Windows 8. Since I'm not usually good at explaining things, here's some pseudo-code to illustrate:

```
function makeFiles()
    createfolder( ".\season\week1" )
    newFile = createFile( ".\season\week1\game.txt" )
    newFile:write( funcThatReturnsAString() )
    newFile:close()
end
```

I know how to open and write to existing files in the same folder as the script, but what I cannot figure out is how to 1) create the subfolder, and 2) create a new file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create folder, you can use `os.execute()` call. For file write, a simple `io.open()` will do the job:

```
function makeFiles()
    os.execute( "mkdir season\\week1" )
    newFile = io.open( "season\\week1\\game.txt", "w+" )
    newFile:write( funcThatReturnsAString() )
    newFile:close()
end
```

---

### EDIT

In Windows, you need to use double backslashes(`\\`) for paths.

Comment: OK, that's simpler than I thought it would be. I thought `io.open()` would return an error if the file didn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`os.execute` works but should be avoided if possible since it is not portable. The [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) library exists for that purpose.

Comment: Got it. `os.execute` is probably fine for this task as the program in question will only ever run on my computer, but I'll keep the portability issue in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
function myCommandFunction(playerid, text)
    if(string.sub(text, 1, 5) == "/save") then
        local aName = getPlayerName(playerid)
        os.execute( "mkdir filterscripts\\account" )
        file = io.open(string.format("filterscripts\\account\\%s.txt", aName), "w")
        file:write(string.format("Name: %s", aName))
        file:close()
    end
end
registerEvent("myCommandFunction", "onPlayerCommand")
```

[Basic: Create accound for game (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OSVR.png)