# How to setup a custom save directory with Love2D

Tags: love2d

I'm currently playing with the [love.graphics.captureScreenshot](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.captureScreenshot) method in my Love2D project, and so far so good. I can see from the wiki example...

```lua
function love.load()
    love.filesystem.setIdentity("screenshot_example")
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == "c" then
        love.graphics.captureScreenshot(os.time() .. ".png")
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.circle("fill", 400, 300, 200)
end
```

...that the screenshots are automatically saved to my Windows 10 directory here...

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\LOVE\screenshot_example`

But how can we setup a custom save directory this way we have a more convenient location as to where these assets can be saved?

Comment: `os.rename` to move it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't with the Löve API, but with Lua.

Löve2D uses PhysFS, an abstraction over the IO functionality, to create a sandboxed environment. This way unexperienced programmers can't accidently delete the whole harddrive or do at least some damage during testing or execution. This means, that on Löves startup (inside the compiled file `boot.lua`), sets the writeable and readable folder, which can't be unset on a later stage. So as of now the Löve API itself, won't allow to save files outside the intended store places.

Lua itself however offers standard `os` and `io` capabilities, which don't go through PhysFS. From there you have several options:

Save the file via Löve2D and then move it to the desired folder via `os.rename` or copy it using `io.open` to read the file and write it at the desired location.

Or you could directly use `io` to save the screenshot at the desired location.

Either way, you could run into two problems:

- How to create a folder
- How to find out, where the user folder is

Be warned, the following code will work only under Windows. If this ain't a problem, go ahead, if you wan't to make it work under linux too, you probably need to adjust some things.

First, Windows saves pictures in `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures`.
We will access the user profile folder via a [environment variable](https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/).
Then we need to create a [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029504/creating-new-folders-and-files-with-lua), if you desire to save those screenshots inside a subdirectory.
Side note: I assume `love.getIdentity` returns the game name.

```lua
local function mkdir(path)
    -- Notice we are using %q to allow for spaces (and prevent command injection)
    os.execute(string.format("mkdir %q", path)) -- System dependant
end

local function combinePaths(...)
    return (table.concat({...}, "\\"):gsub("\\+", "\\")) -- System dependant
end

local saveScreenshot

function love.load()
    love.filesystem.setIdentity("My Game")
    local screenshotDirectory = combinePaths(love.filesystem.getUserDirectory(), "Pictures", love.filesystem.getIdentity())
    mkdir(screenshotDirectory)
    function saveScreenshot()
        local fileName = os.date("%Y.%m.%d--%H-%M-%S")..".png"
        local filePath = combinePaths(love.filesystem.getSaveDirectory(), fileName)
        local destPath = combinePaths(screenshotDirectory, fileName)
        -- We are using a callback, because the screenshot is saved after draw() finishes executing
        ---@param image love.ImageData
        love.graphics.captureScreenshot(function(image)
            image:encode("png", fileName)
            os.rename(filePath, destPath)
        end)
    end
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == "c" then
        saveScreenshot()
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.circle("fill", 400, 300, 200)
end
```